# IndexError: index 21 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 21 & Indexing problem

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, for-loop, matrix, indexing

I am new in Python and I know that similar kind of questions were already here, but they didn't help me to solve my problem.

I have a code snippet:

```
#creating output matrices:
r0_res = np.ones((21,21))
r1_res = np.ones((21,21))

i = 0
j = 0

for jCross in range(280, 300):
    for kLong in range(6850, 6870):
        radObs = dataObs[kLong,jCross,::-1]
        iLow = searchsorted(wGrid,vRange.lower)
        iHigh = searchsorted(wGrid,vRange.upper)
        odg_CH4_rg = interp(wGrid[iLow:iHigh], vGrid, odg_CH4)
        phi0 = radMod1
        phi1 = phi0*odg_CH4_rg 
        aMatrix = np.vstack([phi0, phi1]).T
        r0, r0_alpha = np.linalg.lstsq(aMatrix, radObs[iLow:iHigh])[0]
        r0_res[i, j]= r0
        r1_res[i, j]= r0_alpha
        j=j+1
    i=i+1
```

I need to say that all 'technical' stuff works fine (I've launched it without for-loop), so now I want to put my code snippet into the for-loop of 2 variables.

**My target**: is to read the data massiv (interested area shape: 21*21) and emplement the code to each of the element and write element-wise output 2 variables (*r0* and *r0_alpha*) into 2 different empty matrices (*r0_res* and *r1_res*) respectivly.

I've already tried to change the indexing of observed *jCross* and *kLong* variables, but this does not help and still leads to the same indexing error.

Will be really appreciate for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the problem can be solved by
restricting the created matrices by the size 20*20:

```
r0_res = np.ones((20,20))
r1_res = np.ones((20,20))
```

and using 'if' block at the end:

```
r0, r0_alpha = np.linalg.lstsq(aMatrix, radObs[iLow:iHigh])[0]
if i<= 300:
    r0_res[i, j]= r0 
    r1_res[i, j]= r0_alpha
j=j+1
```